# iOS Significant Location Change while Asleep

Tags: ios, locationmanager

Does the iOS Location Manager's SignificantLocationChange wake the application if the phone is asleep (e.g., in pocket of user)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Location awareness programming guide:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

*If you leave this service running and your application is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your application when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, your application is put into the background and given a small amount of time to process the location data. Because your application is in the background, it should do minimal work and avoid any tasks (such as querying the network) that might prevent it from returning before the allocated time expires. If it does not, your application may be terminated.*